# javascript try catch lifecycle. not printing my defined error

Tags: javascript, try-catch

javascript try catch error, not printing defined error. what's happening here. and why NaN printing.

```js
let num = "sflkj"

try {
    let thenum = parseInt(num)
    console.log(thenum)
} catch (error) {
    console.log("that is not a number.")
}
```

Comment: NaN is a numeric type

Answer (score 1):

Just like the anwser above says NaN is the value parseInt returns, NaN is an abbreviation to Not a Number. It's not an error to go to catch block.

Answer (score 0):

`parseInt`  function does not throw an error and always returns something. if it was not possible to parse the number, then NaN will be returned

Comment: what I should use to throw my own error. I want to try to convert a string number into a number but I don't know if that is a number.